# Create symlink within intellij project

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, gradle, symlink

I am attempting to create a symlink within my project in Intellij, I want to link the index.html from my react folder into my templates folder. I am using this command :

```
ln -s react-app/build/index.html site/src/ratpack/templates/index.html
```

However when I run gradle build I get the error

> Could not list contents of
>   /home/xxx/dev/football/site/src/ratpack/templates/index.html Couldnt
>   follow symbolic link

Am I creating this symlink wrong? I am running the command from the root of my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `file` command to check if that file exists and to know what it is.

> file /home/xxx/dev/football/site/src/ratpack/templates/index.html

if it exists, remove the current broken link with `unlink` command and then create a new one. I suggest to use absolute paths rather than relative paths to create the symbolic link to avoid where are you running the command from.

You are using the command correctly if you are using in the following way:

> ln -s target link_name

Comment: Would I need the link to be relative? As when I deploy the application the absolute path will be wrong? Thanks

Comment: I guess there is no difference if the link it relative or absolute.

The main problem is you (actually gradle build process) is performing a ls command of a path that is not properly set (it cannot follow the symbolic link and that is why ls command fails). The best it to learn how to make symbolic links (relatives and absolutes) on a test folder and then apply what you learn to your project.